# Selenium Webdriver javascript - pop up is getting open 4 times on every dropdown click

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am new to selenium. The scenario is that pop up is getting open when I click on popupid, there are 4 dropdowns in the pop up where i need to select the values from each dropdown but while selecting values from each dropdown new pop up window opens which overrides the existing one. Due to which also facing issue in selecting the correct values.

Selenium code:

```
WebDriverWait waitFortab = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
waitFortab.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".node.settings.asettings.bookmgmt.undefined.ready")));
WebElement el5 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".bookrouting")); // opens the page
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", el5);
WebElement el6 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ruleEnControls .fr.bookroute.addcategory")); // opens up popup
el6.click();
WebDriverWait waitForcategory = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
waitForcategory.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".popup.wrapper.bookroute_save.dffPopup")));
WebElement el8 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".tag.dropdown.product_brm .downArrow.closed"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", el8);
WebElement el9 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Vanilla (V)']")); // selects value from first pop up
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", el9); 

WebElement el10 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".tag.dropdown.currency_pair_brm .downArrow.closed"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", el10);
WebElement el11 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='AUD/CAD']")); // selects value from second pop up
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", el11);

WebElement el12 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".tag.dropdown.currency_brm .downArrow.closed"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", el12);
WebElement el13 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='AUD']"));  // selects value from third pop up
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", el13);
```

HTML Snippet :

```
<ul class="dropdown_menu dn">
  <li class="option selectAllBR" data-value="" shortcut="" data-display="Select All" title="Select All">
  <div class="tag fl checkBoxClear ddselect checkbox r0 c0" irow="0" icol="0" tabindex="0" fieldtype="ddselect" tagtype="checkbox"><input type="hidden" value="0" class="toggleValue value"></div>
  <span class="oLayCheck"></span>Select All</li>
  <li class="option" data-value="euvanilla" shortcut="VANILLA (V)" data-display="Vanilla (V)" title="Vanilla (V)">
  <div class="tag fl checkBoxClear ddselect checkbox r0 c0" irow="0" icol="0" tabindex="0" fieldtype="ddselect" tagtype="checkbox"><input type="hidden" value="0" class="toggleValue value"></div>
  <span class="oLayCheck"></span>Vanilla (V)</li>
  <!-- there are several such <li> elements in each dropdown -->
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet you're running in to some timing issues with the popups being present, but not yet ready on the DOM--so the clicks are happening on the *previous* elements.

Try something like this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
WebElement el8 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".tag.dropdown.product_brm .downArrow.closed"));
wait.until(ExpexctedConditions.elementIsClickable(el8);
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", el8);

WebElement el9 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Vanilla (V)']")); // selects value from first pop up
wait.until(ExpexctedConditions.elementIsClickable(el9);
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", el9);
```

A couple things:

1. You don't need a new wait for different things. Just reuse existing one.
2. Note that the pattern is

   - Find the element
   - Wait for element to be clickable
   - Click the element.
3. Also, not sure why you're using the JavaScriptExecutor. You could simply do "el9.click();" unless there's something goofy with JavaScript on your pop ups.

HTH

Comment: Thanks Jim. It did worked.Also i removed all the JavaScriptExecutor from my code and used simple click instead.Point no.2 is very much helpful

Comment: Glad it helped! Learn to live and breathe by point #2. It's saved me HUGE amounts of grief. (After I had previously had HUGE amounts of grief.)